# Отступы всем, кроме последних 6

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Возникла такая ситуация, допустим, есть 14 блоков, по 6 в ряд, так вот требуется сделать так, чтобы первые 12 имели оступ снизу в размере `24px`, а послений ряд не имел отступов.

Не имею понятия, как это можно провенуть.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 948px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю, чтобы сделать более менее адаптивный вариант, то нужно использовать javascript (если, конечно, не оборачивать каждый ряд в отдельный блок).

Answer (score 2):

Увы, самый простой способ это перестраивать вёрстку (оборачивать каждые 6 блоков во что-нибудь), ну или что-то другое.

Можно визуально убрать отступы.
В вашем случае, блоки имеет отступ внизу на `24px`, просто ставим родителю отступ снизу отрицательный, в такую же величину - `-24px`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 948px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: -24px;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background-color: red;
}

.test {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Зелёный блок показывает, что отступа под `.container` нету.

Comment: Я наверно слепой, покажи плиз, где у автора нижние блоки 24px отступ имеют, я не могу понять этот гоголь-моголь

Comment: @L.F.C., пожалуйста, читайте "допустим, есть 14 блоков, по 6 в ряд, так вот требуется сделать так, чтобы первые 12 имели оступ снизу в размере `24px`"

Comment: Так, я ж так и сделал, или в чём моя ошибка тогда??? Я хочу понять. Читать я умею. И где это автор указал в примере, там такого нет?

Comment: @L.F.C., каверзный вопрос, тут забава в том, чтобы ВСЕМ блокам в ПОСЛЕДНЕМ ряду убрать отступы в размере `24px`

Comment: @L.F.C., да. Но если блоков будет больше\меньше, то код придётся переписывать снова, под последние кол-во элементов в строчке. Думаю об этом вам говорил maine в первом комментарии.

Comment: @L.F.C., я не сколько не хотел оскорбить вас. Просто я уверен, что вопрос тут про "таблицу" с разным кол-вом блоков. Ну и имелось ввиду не "последние два", а "последняя строчка" без отступов.

Comment: Давай на ты пожалуйста, я не мальчишка давно и такая форма общения не удобна :))) Ок, понял, что автор вопрос поставил криво, как я написал в своем комментарии под вопросом, он был бы у нас кофе-рабом с такой постановкой

Comment: @L.F.C., привычка общаться с незнакомыми людьми на вы, так что извини, будем знакомы :D По поводу вопроса, да, задан та он правильно, частично, нужно больше информации и сразу оговаривать условия.

Comment: Ответ удаляю, так как твой более верный при такой постановке задачи

Comment: @L.F.C., не-не-не, не стоит. Вдруг автору вопроса, всё таки, нужен именно твой вариант. Оставь, пусть сам выбирает.

Comment: Поздно.........

Comment: Твой плюсую как верный. Твой вариант более адаптивный. ИМХО

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы просто не использовать гриды?

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 948px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 24px 8px;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.test {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Вариант, вот только с поддержкой беда :с

Comment: правда? https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: Правда, увы, есть люди которые сидят на тех браузерах, которых не поддерживают. Так шо..

Comment: Ну у флекса кстати тоже не 100% поддержка, что ж вы на float ничего не предложили? ))

Comment: Я конечно могу, но какой смысл когда автор вопроса указал свою вёрстку.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 цитата `есть люди которые сидят на тех браузерах, которых не поддерживают. Так шо..`